# Oracle database with Netbeans - not seeing data

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

So I have an Oracle database connected to Netbeans, and when I run a select statement in the Oracle command line I can see the data in the tables.

The problem is that Netbeans database browser doesn't see the data.  I right-click on the table I want to see, and click "view data..." and all my tables show up as empty.

I connected to it using Oracle Thin and ojdbc6.jar if that matters. Just wondering if I missed anything and what could possibly be causing this problem.  I just tried with ojdbc14.jar too and still no data in tables.

UPDATE: So I was able to run an insert using the Netbeans tool for doing so, and it was successful,I can actually see data in my table (Just the one I inserted into).  However, it's the only row I can see in the table, but I can see 5 rows using the Oracle command line.  Not sure what to think of this...

EDIT: Really don't see how it's unclear what the question is... It was already answered too.

Comment: 1) ..do you have a question?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) ...yeah I'm asking for advice.  2) There's no code.  Nothing to be compiled, no example to provide.  Select * from table_name works in the command line, but not in Netbeans.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) Okay, here's my question since it's apparently not obvious: "What advice would you give to a person with the problems in the OP?  Have any of you ever had this problem and if so how did you fix it?" 

2) You don't understand, there's literally no code, I haven't written any yet because I can't get the database connection working properly.  Netbeans has a tool that lets you view the data in a database you're connected to.  I'm not seeing any of the data that's in the database.  I know there's data in the database because I can see it in the Oracle command line.

Comment: @AndrewThompson A DB query tool is part of Netbeans since a few versions ago.

Comment: Why is this question on hold?  It was already answered by Loki.  Which should also tell you guys that it wasn't unclear what I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using netbeans to browse database? You should be using a proper sql client to browse database table.
So i would recommend you to use SQL developer or Squirrel or Toad.

Secondly , are you sure data is committed to DB which you are trying to view? This is the most likely cause.

So this is what you should do:

1. Try to connect to DB from different SQL clients and see if you are able to view data from them.
2. If none of clients are able to view data then for sure data is not committed else Netbeans has some issue.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks.  I didn't realize I had to commit, but now that you mention it, it makes sense.  I could see the data in the Oracle command prompt, but not anywhere else.  And I'm using Netbeans because I'm just making a Java program and I couldn't get any data from my database.  Netbeans and Eclipse are all I know lol.

Comment: Start using using SQL clients to browse data in DB, they are meant for that purpose. I would recommend oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Yeah that's the plan, I was just using the command line until now.  Command lines aren't terribly efficient for workflow lol.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this as some IDE issue which you are facing.

- Have you tried reconnecting to Oracle from Netbeans?
- Try restarting the IDE itself (IDE restart helps in a lot of cases, mostly with
  Eclipse).

If all fails, try using *SQLDeveloper* for working on the database which would have more functionality (and more stability possibly) than the IDE plugin (though both seem to be using a thin driver).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried several times (might try eclipse soon even though I hate it).  Not sure what SQL Developer is, but I'm willing to try anything at this point.  Also I'm going to update the OP with something new I tried if you care to look at that.